# Cannot pass an option to a command in commander.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to pass an option to a command that I created with commander.js...

```
program
 .command('init [options]')
 .description('scaffold the project')
 .option('-b, --build', 'add "build" folder with subfolders')
 .action(function(){
   if(program.build) {
    mkdirp("build/")
  }
 });

program.parse(process.argv);
```

...where if the `-b` flag is passed to `init`, the npm `mkdirp` module creates a "build" directory. Sadly, I can't get it working...any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change program.build to this.build inside the function passed to .action()

```
program
 .command('init [options]')
 .description('scaffold the project')
 .option('-b, --build', 'add "build" folder with subfolders')
 .action(function(){
   if(this.build) {
    mkdirp("build/")
  }
 });

program.parse(process.argv);
```

Comment: It's always something simple...and obvious.  Thanks much!